# How to call a function on 'load' event in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dom-events

Apologies for my Javascript inexperience. I am a JavaScript and D3 newbie, trying to adapt [the subway wait assessment example](https://github.com/mikedewar/getting_started_with_d3/blob/master/visualisations/subway_wait_assessment_UI.html) from [Mike Dewar's Getting Started with D3 book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025429.do).

As given, the example loads with none of the subway lines plotted -- you will have to click one to plot it. I thought it would be simple to change the code so that, when the visualization starts up, one of the lines (say the "A" line) is already plotted by default.

I can do this by copying and pasting part of the code from inside the get_timeseries_data function in Dewar's script (which does some checks and calls a draw_timeseries function). But this seems wrong. The point of writing a function is that I should be able to call get_timeseries_data itself directly, no?

Since Dewar's final code chunk there uses selection.on('click'), it seemed logical to mimic this but using .on('load') instead:

```
d3.select('#Line_A_key')
  .on('load', get_timeseries_data);
```

Adding this to the end of the script does not work. It doesn't even give an error in the console, so I guess the 'load' event just never happens -- why?

So I thought maybe I can just call the get_timeseries_data function directly without waiting for a 'load' event:

```
d3.select('#Line_A_key')
  .get_timeseries_data();
```

But this complains that the object has no method 'get_timeseries_data'. Okay, this is true, but begs the question -- when **can** I call a function in D3?

D3 (or is it all of JS?) seems to have certain situations where it expects a function that takes data and index as its parameters. How do I learn what these situations are? And if I already have a function in this form, can I also call it outside of these situations, or do I need to write a whole new function for other cases?

I haven't been able to answer these questions for myself from browsing the D3 API, or from any of several online tutorials, and most unfortunately not from Dewar's book either. Where should I have looked instead?

Comment: I can't address the whole question, but I think some of your confusion comes from not understanding what parts of the code are executing synchronously and what parts are async and waiting for response from server (e.g. the download of time series .JSON data from the server). The .data function of D3 is expecting the data you pass it to already exist in memory, which is why you can't introduce a server call in the middle of it.

Comment: That is definitely true. Thanks for the tip. I will try to learn more about that side of things.

Comment: Did you get the first example to work? I can't get my code to display any of the information in the json file.

Answer (score 2):

#Line_A_key may not be loaded. So you can't select it...

```
d3.select(window).on("load", get_timeseries_data);
```